# Search with tag finds only one question

Tags: support, tags, search

I would like to search for my questions that contain the tag [docker](/questions/tagged/docker), so I tried searching for:

```
user:me tag[docker]
```

This brings me only one question. Where are the rest?

Comment: In fact, it brought you [one result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334067/permission-denied-while-creating-image-from-scratch) because it contains both "tag" and "docker". I wonder how is `g[d` interpreted by the search engine.

Comment: Find detailed search options in [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `tag` part, just place the tag in brackets:

```
user:me [docker]
```

This will yield [more than 1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1501700%20%5Bdocker%5D).